# Mensaje whatsapp a un numero no resgitrado

Tags: ionic, ionic3, ionic2, ionic-framework, ionic4

estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde en la parte de contacto pueda enviar un mensaje predeterminado a un numero especifico no registrado y abra la aplicación de whatsapp, no se si debe descargar algun plugin para esto, he revisado varias preguntas en stackoverflow en ingles y una solucion es esta.

[image: aqui declare el numero y el mensaje que quiero que contenga]

[image: y declare esto en el config.xml]

Comment: ¡Hola! Bienvenido. Como recomendación, procura compartir tu código, los errores, los datos de prueba, siempre como texto. Replicar errores desde imágenes puede ser complicado y se hace difícil de ver para quienes entran desde móviles o tienen alguna discapacidad. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: PD. CUando sigues esa solución de SO en inglés, ¿funciona? Sale algún error?

Comment: hola buenas no he intentado realizarla lo que si he intentado es el href sin la modificacion del xml, toca que pruebe.

Comment: Jeje, no, al contrario. Puedes probar y nos cuentas si te sirve

Comment: listo amigo funciona asi como esta en la imagen, el numero telefonico se coloca sin el + y sin los parentesis, sencillo y sin descargar plugins

Comment: Te puedes responder a ti mismo y, creo que un par de días después, puedes marcarla como la respuesta aceptada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para enviar un mensaje a un numero no registrado como contacto, los pasos son fáciles.

1.- crea un boton o una etiqueta y agrega este href:"whatsapp://send?phone=numero_telefónico?text=Mensaje_enviar_por_defecto".

nota: el numero telefónico se coloca sin el + antes del código del país y sin paréntesis.

2.- luego de esto debes colocar en el config.xml el siguiente código:

nota: este código hará que se envié el mensaje a través de la aplicación.

fácil, sencillo, rápido y sin la necesidad de descargar plugins innecesarios.